# .each Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jquery and I have a problem with the code bellow.

this is my code

```
.done(function (result) {
           var data = [];
           result.each(function (index) {
               var obj = {};
               obj.label = result[index].Campaign;
               if (result[index].Count == 0) {
                   obj.data = 0;
               } else {
                   obj.data = result[index].SL / result[index].Count;
               }
               data.push(obj);
           })
.....
.....
})
```

I got `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` on the `each` function

why please?

Comment: What is `result`?  I'm gonna guess it's not a jQuery object, and therefore doesn't have an `each` function.  `result.each` is `undefined` and "undefined is not a function".

Comment: @RocketHazmat the result from json call. I have data in that result I can see it in my chrome debugging tool

Comment: @RocketHazmat do you want to show you the `result` ?

Comment: You meant `result.forEach` maybe?

Comment: @BatuZet what is the difference? I used each. is it wrong ?

Comment: @RocketHazmat it is not ajax. it is from `$.getJSON('url',{ fromDate: "01-01-2014", toDate: "09-04-2014" })` this call

Comment: Yes, it is wrong.  `.each` is a function that exists on jQuery objects.  What you are getting from your AJAX/JSONP call is just an object.

Comment: @RocketHazmat what should I do to loop on that result please? `forEach` ?

Comment: See [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23062356/206403) that @Pointy posted.

Comment: `forEach` is to loop through inside an `array` in pure js and u can get the values you need inside that loop like `index[key]`.

Comment: @RocketHazmat in that answer, what is the `value` please. can I say `value.Count` instead of `result[index].Count` ?

Comment: @user3432257L Yep.  That's correct.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The value in the "result" parameter is not a jQuery object, and there's no "each" property. Thus, `result.each` is `undefined`, and you're trying to use that as a function.

You probably want `$.each()`:

```
$.each(result, function(index, value) { ... });
```

Comment: what is the `value` ? is the like `result[index]` ?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have not used the correct syntax for using jQuery's "each" function. For e.g.

```
$.each( obj, function( key, value ) {
    alert( key + ": " + value );
});
```

For more information, you can check https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

Comment: what is the `value` is the result[index] please?

Answer (score 0):

*result* parameter should be a list.

"*.each*" function is jQuery extension for list/arrays or can be supplied with one.

Here is more: [$.each function](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)